# Finding the limit of a sequence with cube roots and fourth root

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm in a mechanical engineering school in France and I'm studying sequences in maths and I don't feel to confident on this topic so I decided to do some exercices I've found in books of the school's library. In one of these exercises, I have to find the limit of this sequence but I never encountered cube roots and fourth root before. Is there anything I need to be aware of when finding the limit?
$$\frac{3\sqrt[3]{n}+\sqrt{n+2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[4]{n^{2}+1}}{4\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n+1}}$$

I know that is a limit with infinity over infinity and you have to factorize by the element of highest degree but how can you take elements out of cube roots or fourth roots, can you do the same as in square roots ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{3\sqrt[3]{n}+\sqrt{n+2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt[4]{n^{2}+1}}{4\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n+1}}=
\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(3n^{-1/6}+\sqrt{1+2n^{-1/2}}+\sqrt[4]{1+n^{-2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}\left(4+(n^{-1/2}+n^{-3/2})^{1/3}\right)}.$$

P.S. After dividing the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{n}$, we have that as $n\to +\infty$ the limit is $\frac{0+1+1}{4+0}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I can't see why the exponents become negative $$3\sqrt[3]{(n)}=3\sqrt{(n)}n^{1/6}$$ is this expression right? If it is, why do you have $-1/3$ ?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{n}\cdot n^{-1/6}=n^{1/2-1/6}=n^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{n}$.
Starting from the RHS, perform the multiplications and you will obtain the LHS.

Comment: Then you just have to say that the elements with a negative exponent have their limit going to 0 and the limit is 1/2 ?

Comment: Yes, the limit is $(1+1)/4=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Divide everything by $\sqrt{n}$. Now, for example, $\frac{\sqrt[4]{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = n^{-1/4}$. And $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{n^2+1}{n^{3/2}}}$ and so forth.